# Account for scrollbar width in floating auto-sized ExtJS panel

Tags: extjs, scrollbar

Here's my problem, using ExtJS 4.1.1: I've got a floating panel whose contents may change in size over time. I'd like to have the floating panel resize around the content, but cap the height to a maximum 400 pixels, after which point a vertical scrollbar should appear.

This JSFiddle explains the problem best: http://jsfiddle.net/38Kaf/6/ .

When the content size is below the maxHeight, the auto-sizing works beautifully. But when it's larger (350px or more), the panel width is too small to contain both the blue box *and* the vertical scrollbar, causing the horizontal scrolling to appear.

Note that neither of the layout properties ('manageOverflow' and 'reserveScrollbar') have any effect.

Any suggestions for workarounds or alternative approaches are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You have specified layout properties, but you haven't specified layout type:

```
layout: {
    type: 'fit',
    manageOverflow: 1,
    reserveScrollbar: true
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Close, but no cigar: the 'fit' layout doesn't listen to the maxHeight property, so I get no scrollbar when the content is taller than 300px (i.e., the content is sized to the max-height).

http://jsfiddle.net/38Kaf/11/